# On Windows 8 how an I adjust the touchscreen scrolling momentum

Tags: windows-8, scrolling, touchscreen

I have two Windows 8 devices -- A Surface RT and a Toshiba all-in-one.  On the Surface if I do a fast swipe from right-to-left the screen scrolls quickly and continues to scroll after I've lifted my finger off the screen (ala Wheel of Fortune).

But on the Toshiba all-in-one (LX835), the scrolling pretty much ends when my finger lifts off the screen.  The items don't continue to scroll (well maybe for a fraction of a second).

How do I change the momentum scrolling such that the Toshiba touch scrolling behaves like the Surface?

Comment: Have you checked the bundled driver software for touch sensitivity settings?

Comment: I did a fresh re-install of Windows 8 after getting the device, so there is no bundled software at this point.

Comment: Windows might have detected the hardware and installed appropriate drivers (that might have those settings) from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

l found that solution online, it will help you. The param "Friction" under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch]. You can set it to numeric values from 0-64. 64 means high friction, 0 means very low friction. Of course i chose 0 to make scrolling after swiping really fast. I needed a reboot to make this effective. Remember there are a couple of copies of this registry structure under [HKEY_USERS], you should set them too (execpt for the very improbable case that some user wants slow touch scrolling).